# Seeing voting progress?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, election

Is there any way to look at the progress in voting on moderator candidates ? I obviously don't need to know the votes for each candidate, but I'd like to know how many people have voted, so as to decide how much  GOTV to do.

Disclaimer: I'm a moderator on cstheory and a candidate in our first round of post-beta elections.

Comment: Get Out The Vote!!!!

Comment: Sorry. US-centric terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a moderator look for changes around election stats on the next build.